# Table name in Stored Procedure as Parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure splitting source table into 4 tables which is working fine. See following.

SO NOW I CHANGED TO FOLLOWING ONE

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Doc124NEW_new (@DMIGRATIONNEW nvarchar(255)) 


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


DECLARE @DMIGRATION nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @count int = 0;
DECLARE @numRows int = 0;

SELECT @DMIGRATION = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @DMIGRATIONNEW

--SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM '+@DMIGRATION+'

SELECT  @count = p.rows 
FROM    sys.partitions p
JOIN    sys.tables t
ON      p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
AND     p.index_id < 2
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id]) = @DMIGRATION
SELECT @numRows = @count / 4

DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql='SELECT TOP  '+ @numRows +' * 
INTO [dbo].[DMIGRATIONnew1]
FROM '+@DMIGRATION
EXEC(@SQL)


DECLARE @sql1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql1= 'SELECT TOP '+@numRows+' * 
INTO [dbo].[DMIGRATIONnew2]
FROM '+@DMIGRATION+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+@numRows+' [cindex] FROM '+@DMIGRATION+')'
EXEC(@SQL1)

DECLARE @sql2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql2='SELECT TOP '+@numRows+' * 
INTO [dbo].[DMIGRATIONnew3]
FROM '+@DMIGRATION+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+@numRows+' * 2 [cindex] FROM '+@DMIGRATION+')'

EXEC(@SQL2)

DECLARE @sql3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @sql3='SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[DMIGRATIONnew4]
FROM '+@DMIGRATION+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+@numRows+' * 3 [cindex] FROM '+@DMIGRATION+')'
EXEC(@SQL3)

END
```

AND GETTING ERROR LIKE
***Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT TOP  ' to data type int.***

here is the error message followed by SP

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '2'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '3'.

```
alter PROCEDURE Doc124NEW_new1 (@DOCMIGRATIONNEW nvarchar(255)) 


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--DROP TABLE [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew1]
--DROP TABLE [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew2] 
--DROP TABLE [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew3]
--DROP TABLE [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew4]

DECLARE @DOCMIGRATION nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @count int = 0;
DECLARE @numRows int = 0;
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @DOCMIGRATION = QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME )
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @DOCMIGRATIONNEW

--SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+'

SELECT  @count = p.rows 
FROM    sys.partitions p
JOIN    sys.tables t
ON      p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
AND     p.index_id < 2
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id]) = @DOCMIGRATION
SELECT @numRows = @count / 4


SELECT @sql='SELECT TOP ('+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+') * 
INTO [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew1]
FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION
EXEC(@SQL)



SELECT @sql1= 'SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' * 
INTO [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew2]
FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' [cindex] FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+')'
EXEC(@SQL1)


SELECT @sql2='SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' * 
INTO [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew3]
FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' * 2 [cindex] FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+')'
EXEC(@SQL2)


SELECT @sql3='SELECT * 
INTO [dbo].[DOCMIGRATIONnew4]
FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' * 3 [cindex] FROM '+@DOCMIGRATION+')'
EXEC(@SQL3)

END
```

Comment: Wanting to treat multiple tables identically is often a sign of a broken data model - why is all of this data not in a *single* table with the *data* that currently determines which table a row belongs to explicitly modelled as one or more columns?

Comment: It's just because when we run the job for importing from single table which takes more time as compared to 4 small tables.

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTENAME()` with no other [character string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx#Anchor_0) is going to wrap your table name in square brackets.

So when, further down you look for

```
SELECT @count = 'COUNT(*) FROM ['+@DMIGRATION+']'
```

you are basically writing this

```
SELECT @count = 'COUNT(*) FROM [[TABLE_NAME]]'
```

Remove the addition of square brackets and it should work for you.

---

You have also defined your `@count` variable as an INT but when you try to set it to a value, you appear to be attempting to set it to a string.

```
SELECT @count = 'COUNT(*) FROM ['+@DMIGRATION+']';
```

Instead try to get the rows from the `sys.partitions` tables

```
SELECT  @count = p.rows 
FROM    sys.partitions p
JOIN    sys.tables t
ON      p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
AND     p.index_id < 2
WHERE   OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id]) = @DMIGRATION;
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything into those 4 "Select Top " queries into bottom.

Comment: Yup, square brackets means that SQL Server is going to look for a table called @DMIGRATION, not a variable table (it's how we can get away with having spaces and other bad characters in our table names).
So your `NOT IN (SELECT`s and `INTO ... FROM [@` needs to have the square brackets gone too.

Comment: I got following error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Select COUNT(*) FROM [docmigrationCCAC]' to data type int."

Comment: USE [DMIGRATION]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE Doc124NEW_new (@DMIGRATIONNEW nvarchar(255))

Comment: This give me error saying incorrect synntax near SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM '+@docmigration+'

Comment: I hope you got my edited code which I replaced in my actual question

Comment: Change your `SELECT @count` for what I updated my answer with and see if that helps you.

Comment: I did changes and it helped also but now the error is further down to DECLARE sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT sql='SELECT TOP  '+ numRows +' * 
INTO [dbo].[DMIGRATIONnew1]
FROM '+DMIGRATION
EXEC(SQL) where it says  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT TOP (' to data type int.

Comment: I removed @sign because it was not allowing me to post

Comment: Another issue with your datatypes @user2040021, to add @numRows (**INT**) to a string like you are attempting to do, you need to `convert` or `cast` it.
`sql='SELECT TOP  '+ CAST(@numRows AS varchar(6)) +' *...`

Comment: Looks like this error are getting down to bottom and will eventually out of SP lol.

Comment: Now getting following error Error message
Invalid column name 'cindex' It was ok when hardcoded table name but now not

Comment: SELECT @sql1= 'SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' * 
INTO [dbo].[docmigrationnew2]
FROM '+@docmigration+'
WHERE [cindex] NOT IN (SELECT TOP '+CAST(@numRows AS NVARCHAR(6))+' [cindex] FROM '+@docmigration+')'

Comment: ...is there a column called [cindex] in your table?

Comment: And I assume that your Collation is not Case Sensitive? I would also add a N before every apostrophe as you have @sql declared as NVARCHAR... so `SELECT @sql1 = N'SELECT TOP' ... + N'...`

Comment: It still says Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'cindex'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'cindex'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'cindex'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'cindex'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'cindex'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Invalid column name 'cindex'.

Comment: Okay, add your new code to your answer under your original code with the error message and it'll get reviewed